# Cannot find a Git object in its objects tree

Tags: git

My git repository works fine without any change in working directory.

I checked the the SHA-1 hash of a file with `git hash-object file.txt`, but cannot get the object named by the SHA-1 hash in `.git\objects` (first 2 characters are eliminated in the search and other files work file).

I can see the SHA-1 hash in git tree object and `git cat-file -p xxxxxxx` works on it. Is there some optimization for the storage under `.git\objects`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [the database is occasionally packed](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles).

Answer (score 1):

Type `git ls-tree` to view the SHA-1 of each file.
To display the content of the SHA-1 as you already know: `git cat-file -p SHA-1`